# load images with ajax or serverside

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to optimize my page and minify load times. I have a few images on my site, where I don't know, how to load them.

1) doing this with an ajax call
example:

```
<div class="banner_content" id="top_content">
<script language="JavaScript">
     getBanner(); 
     function getBanner(){
          getAjaxData('load_image.asp','top_content'); 
          setTimeout('getBanner()',120000);
     }
</script>
```

2) doing this server side
example:

```
<img src="">
```

which one has faster loading times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page which has the image in the HTML will load faster then the page that adds an image to the HTML using information gleaned from an additional HTTP request that isn't even made until a time delay expires.

Answer (score 0):

You could check this examples out
http://robnyman.github.io/html5demos/localstorage/